# Trigger not calling for huge rows insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table which consists of one trigger which will be called if any insert or update operation performed on that table.

This trigger will insert a new row in other physical table.

First I am taking the entire data to be inserted into a temporary table and then I am inserting data into my physical table(which has trigger).

After performing insert operation all the records in the temporary table are getting inserted into physical table but the trigger is executing for only first record, for rest of the records it is not executing.

Can anyone please help me with this issue.

NOTE : With cursor it is working fine but for performance issue I don't want to use cursor.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MY_TRG]  
ON [dbo].[T_EMP_DETAILS]  
FOR INSERT , UPDATE  
AS  
BEGIN   
IF UPDATE(S_EMPLOYEE_ID)OR UPDATE(S_GRADE_ID)OR UPDATE(D_EFFECTIVE_DATE)  OR UPDATE(S_EMPLOYEE_STATUS)  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @EmpId varchar(6)  
DECLARE @HeaderId Int  
DECLARE @FYStartYear varchar(4)  
DECLARE @EffDate Smalldatetime  
DECLARE @UpdatedBy varchar(10)  
DECLARE @ActionType varchar(1)  
DECLARE @RowCount Int  
DECLARE @EmpRowCount Int  
DECLARE @AuditRowsCount Int   
DECLARE @EMP_STATUS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @D_FIN_START_YEAR DATETIME
DECLARE @Food_Count int

SELECT @FYStartYear =  CAST(YEAR(D_CURRENT_FY_ST_DATE)AS VARCHAR) FROM dbo.APPLICATION  WHERE B_IS_CURRENT_FY = 1  

SELECT @UpdatedBy = 'SHARDUL'  

select  @EmpId =  S_EMPLOYEE_ID from inserted  
select  @HeaderId =  N_HEADER_TXN_ID from inserted  
select @EffDate = D_EFFECTIVE_DATE from inserted 
select @FLEXI_AMT = N_FLEX_BASKET_AMT  from inserted  
select @EMP_STATUS = S_EMPLOYEE_STATUS from inserted   
select @D_FIN_START_YEAR=D_FIN_START_DATE  from inserted

SELECT @RowCount =  count(*) from T_EMP_DETAILS  
WHERE S_EMPLOYEE_ID = @EmpId and   
SUBSTRING(CAST(D_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS VARCHAR),1,11) =       SUBSTRING(CAST(@EffDate AS VARCHAR),1,11)  

BEGIN  
exec  INSERT_DEFAULT_VALUES @EmpId,@HeaderId,@UpdatedBy 
END
```

Comment: Show your trigger code. I am bet you are not using `inserted` table in it, or use it improper way.

Comment: Are you sure the trigger is not executing per-batch instead with the `INSERT` operation data as multiple records in the `inserted` table?

Comment: An `INSERT` trigger will execute once per `INSERT` statement. If a single `INSERT` statement inserts multiple rows, the trigger will nevertheless fire only once, and the `inserted` pseudo-table will contain all the rows inserted. Either your trigger is wrong, or you're expecting the wrong things from it.

Comment: @Charleh I am not sure how to identify whether trigger is executing per-batch or per record

Comment: @JeroenMostert My trigger is inserting only single row in single table.

Comment: @Shardul: then it was written to work that way. If you want it to do something else, rewrite it (or ask the author to). All triggers always execute once per statement, never per row. It's up to the trigger to handle multiple rows separately.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of many reasons Bulk is so fast :). Read [Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx) syntax and you'll see `FIRE_TRIGGERS` parameter. Use it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am not using the BULK INSERT functionality. I am just inserting huge amount of records from temporary table to physical table(containing trigger which will insert one new row in another physical table.)

Comment: I am inserting 5000 records from temporary table to physical table but the trigger is getting triggered only for first entry, for remaining it is executing the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment - you are using `inserted` in improper way. As written now it will work only for 1 row.

The second one is a WEIRD number of variables, and only few are used, why?

Third - you are using SP in the end of batch, you need to post it's code, I bet there is some insert in it, maybe you could avoid using this SP and insert directly in some table from inserted.